# top count for a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have a variable for selecting top rows. I can select top rows based on a variable. However I want to select all rows if the variable is not supplied.

Currently I'm using this query:

```
DECLARE @TOPCOUNT int;
SET @TOPCOUNT=10;

SELECT TOP(@TOPCOUNT) * FROM TABLE1
```

**Update:**

1. The original query is very lengthy and complex, so I don't to rewrite the entire query without top count in else clause.
2. I don't want to use dynamic query because of its repercussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @TOPCOUNT int;
--SET @TOPCOUNT=10;

IF @TOPCOUNT IS NULL
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1
ELSE
    SELECT TOP(@TOPCOUNT) * FROM TABLE1
```

Added after above UPDATE - if this is a parameter of a Stored Procedure then just provide a default for `@TOPCOUNT`:

```
@TOPCOUNT INT = 2147483647 --max size of INT
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will help. Just init your @TOPCOUNT with -1 if you want all rows.

```
IF @TOPCOUNT = -1 BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM TABLE1
END
ELSE BEGIN
  SELECT TOP(@TOPCOUNT) * FROM TABLE1
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IF @TOPCOUNT IS NULL SET @TOPCOUNT=2147483647
```

Comment: To select ALL rows as the OP asked rather than no rows shouldn't this be `IF @TOPCOUNT IS NULL SET @TOPCOUNT=2147483647 \\max size of INT`?

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not able to test it currently, but i thought top 0 is the same as not specifying top at all.

Comment: No, `TOP (0)` will return - surprise - 0 rows!